# What are the security implications of knowing the private polynomial $\mathcal{F}$

Tags: cryptanalysis, post-quantum-cryptography, multivariate-cryptography

First, affine transformations $S,T$ are defined by $S=A_1+v_s, T=A_2+v_t$. Let the private polynomial function $\mathcal{F}$ be known. The short description of the public key map is $P(X) = T \circ \mathcal{F} \circ S(X)$. Recall that common multivariate schemes are based on the security assumption of **IP2**, this is, the *Isomorphism Of Polynomials with two secrets*.

It results that only applying transformations $T$ and $S=I_n$ (the identity) makes the scheme vulnerable by linear algebra attacks. We can recover the transformation matrix $T$ since we already know that it transformed $\mathcal{F}$ to the public key matrix.

In addition, using $T=I_n$ and $S$ an arbitrary invertible affine function, the problem now is equivalent to **IP1**, which can be stated from the so called *Polynomial Affine Equivalence* problem (PAE) (see [[1]](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F11426639_21.pdf) section $2.3$ and $3$). Given $\mathcal{F}(x)$ and $\mathcal{F}(S(x))$ find $S$. Schemes based on **IP1** can be vulnerable to attacks if not designed with care, see [[2]](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071464/document).

Then we are restricted to IP2 if we want to mantain security from this point. Recall that including abritrary invertible affine transformations $S,T$ would make the input-output of $\mathcal{F}$ unknown, even knowing $\mathcal{F}$. Then as $T$ transforms an unknown input, we learn nothing from here nor from the view of **PAE** or **IP1**, as we only know one set of quadratic equations $B$ but the set $A$ remains hidden by the transformation $T$.

---

In the previous description I tried to demonstrate that the knowledge of the private polynomial $\mathcal{F}$ has no effect when the scheme is based on the assumptions of **IP2**.

However, **is there any complication** if the private polynomial $\mathcal{F}$ is publicly known from other perspective?

**My intiution says that** recovering $T$ is fatal as $\mathcal{F}(X), \mathcal{F^{-1}}(X)$ are known the attacker obtains $F^{-1}(Y)=S(X)$. Then to solve **IP1** he must establish an affine equivalence function $S$ between $\mathcal{F}(X)$ and $\mathcal{F}(S(X))$

If the attacker doesn't possess $\mathcal{F}$ knowing $T$ will yield $F \circ S(X)$ but yet he doesn't know $\mathcal{F}(X)$, thus **IP1** cannot be followed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's answer my question after revisiting the research. Start by quoting the following text from [[2]](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071464/document). Note that I've changed the variables names to fit my description. Here $P(X) = T \circ F \circ S(X)$.

> An open question is to know whether or not these schemes remain secure
>   if the set of polynomials $\mathcal{F}$ is public. In this situation,
>   the security of these schemes relies not only on the difficulty of
>   finding a common zero of a system of non linear equations but also on
>   the difficulty of $\mathcal{IP}$ (Isomorphism of Polynomials) problem
>   (when $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ are given, the problem is to recover the
>   pairs $(A_1,v_s)$ and $(A_2,v_t)$).

In this post the private polynomial $\mathcal{F}$ is public, moreover described methods reduce **IP2** to **IP1** if $T$ is known, and **IP1** is totally insecure [[2]](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071464/document). In the other hand, if $S$ is known $T$ is recovered by basic linear algebra.

Then I conclude that a cryptosystem where $\mathcal{F}$ is known depends on the **IP2** assumption (finding $(S,T))$ and the $\mathcal{MQ}$ problem implicitly. You can follow up from [[2](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071464/document)] section $6.2$

**EDIT**: Moreover, it results that **IP1** is totally broken when the private polynomial is known. However if the polynomial $\mathcal{F}$ is unknown, having access to an oracle then querying for canonical vectors as a plaintext will reveal $S$ too. A secure cryptosystem based on MPKC must satisfy the **IP2** assumption from design, between others.